# Using a class within it's own declaration

Tags: c++, list, copy, private

ok, so my problem is this. I need to copy a custom made list and the function has to be a private member of my list-class. looks like this atm:

```
private:
struct List_Node* head_;
List* copy(List* list);
```

looks like crap i know, but i have been told to do it that way.
getting the compilation error:

```
error: `List* List::copy(List*)' is private
```

is there some way to go around this problem or am i understanding my directions wrong?

Comment: That's not nearly enough code.

Comment: it depends on where you call this function. This 'copy' method can be called only from other method of this class

Comment: If it is C++, then "struct List_Node*" may be changed simply to "List_Node*". However, you didn't tell, where the error occured and how have you tried to use it.

Comment: Do you really need to call a `copy` function? You can use copy-constructor or overload operator `=` to copy data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the function from within another member function which is `public`.

You cannot call `private` member functions from outside the class. The error suggests you are doing that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling the `List::copy` from within member functions of `List` (as the title indicates), you should have no problem.

If you want to call it from outside the class, you will not get access to the private member functions (e.g. `copy`) unless you declare the caller function a `friend` of the class

Answer (score 0):

Try to use copy-constructor or operator `=` overloading.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are told to do so because the users of this class are not supposed to copy the list directly. The list node is also declared as a private structure, which is inaccessible to outside functions. The construction and destruction of the list node should be handled by member methods of this class.

May be because of these reasons, the copy method should be protected, in this case, declared as private.

You can call the private copy method in any member methods of this class, including public methods.

Although it is unlikely to happen, you can simply declare a public member method only calling this private method, which expose the private method to outside functions. However, it will be non-sense to declare the copy method private in the first place.